# how to match strings of vectors with dataframe column in R

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in r

```
Id    titles
1     emami paper mills slips 10% on dismal q4 numbers
2     jsw steel q4fy17 standalone net profit rises 173.33%
3     fmcg major hul q4fy17 standalone net profit rises 6.2
4     chennai petroleum, allsec tech slip 6-7% on poor q4
```

And, I have names in vectors

```
names <- c("emami ltd","jsw steel ltd","abc","hul india ltd","tcs","chennai petroleum corp ltd")
```

I want to match the dataframe column titles with strings of vectors and print corresponding string in a new column. My desired dataframe is

```
 Id    titles                                                    names
1     emami paper mills slips 10% on dismal q4 numbers           emami ltd
2     jsw steel q4fy17 standalone net profit rises 173.33%       jsw steel ltd
3     fmcg major hul q4fy17 standalone net profit rises 6.2      hul india ltd
4     chennai petroleum, allsec tech slip 6-7% on poor q4        chennai petroleum corp ltd
```

I am doing it with following code,but it does not give me what I want.

```
df[grepl(paste(names, collapse="|"), df$titles),]
```

How to do it in R?

Comment: That's because none of the titles have the `"ltd"` string in them. I.e. in your first title there is only `"emami"`, not `"emami ltd"`

Comment: so,how would I do it ?

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want the `"ltd"` in your lookup correct?

Comment: no,I do not want that.

Comment: Is the third one incorrect? For example, do you want to match `"hul india"` only or `hul` or `india`?

Comment: only hul not india

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly then , you can use BaseR's `gregexpr` along with `regematches` and `gsub` to complete your task.

**Data**: EDIT After OP has changed the question

```
options(stringsAsFactors = F)
df <- data.frame(titles = c("emami paper mills slips 10% on dismal q4 numbers",
                            "jsw steel q4fy17 standalone net profit rises 173.33%",
                            "fmcg major hul q4fy17 standalone net profit rises 6.2",
                            "chennai petroleum, allsec tech slip 6-7% on poor q4"),stringsAsFactors = F)

names <- c("emami ltd","jsw steel ltd","abc","hul india ltd","tcs","chennai petroleum corp ltd")
```

**Regex**:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

newnames <- gsub("^(\\w+).*","\\1",names)
regmat <- regmatches(df$titles,gregexpr(paste0(newnames,collapse="|"),df$titles))
regmat[lapply(regmat,length) == 0] <- NA
df <- data.frame(cbind(df,newnames =do.call("rbind",regmat)),stringsAsFactors = F)
df1 <- data.frame(names=names,newnames=newnames,stringsAsFactors = F)
left_join(df,df1,by="newnames")
```

You can also use `stringr` library like below:

```
library(stringr)
newnames <- str_replace(names,"^(\\w+).*","\\1")
df$newnames <- str_extract(df$titles,paste0(newnames,collapse="|"))
df1 <- data.frame(names=names,newnames=newnames,stringsAsFactors = F)
left_join(df,df1,by="newnames")
```

**output**:

```
    > left_join(df,df1,by="newnames")
                                                 titles newnames                      names
1      emami paper mills slips 10% on dismal q4 numbers    emami                  emami ltd
2  jsw steel q4fy17 standalone net profit rises 173.33%      jsw              jsw steel ltd
3 fmcg major hul q4fy17 standalone net profit rises 6.2      hul              hul india ltd
4   chennai petroleum, allsec tech slip 6-7% on poor q4  chennai chennai petroleum corp ltd
```

Comment: When I give following names `names <- c("emami","jsw steel","abc","tcs")` and run your code keeping the `df` as above. It thows an error `Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "newnames", value = c("emami", "jsw steel" : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 3`

Comment: @Neil you are missing "hul india ltd" in your vector, it is tested on two system can't be wrong.

Comment: @Neil , I have added another solution on stringr, you may check that as well

Comment: many of my names contains `gujarat state petronet,hcl infosystems,hester pharm,high ground enterprise` your code does not recognize these. `1str_replace(names,"^(\\w+).*","\\1")` this code removes text after space.

Comment: @Neil Offcourse it wont match.Please put that in your question.Make your question which should be a reflection of your problem to get a generic solution. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got it corrected. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ltd from your names :

```
names <- gsub(" ltd","",names)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to use `sqldf` for this type of "fuzzy" merge.

*Construct lookup:*

```
names <- data.frame(name = c("emami ltd","jsw steel ltd","abc","hul india ltd","tcs"))
names$lookup <- gsub("(\\w+).*", "\\1", names$name)
```

*Perform merge:*

```
library(sqldf)
res <- sqldf("SELECT l.*, r.name
       FROM df as l
       LEFT JOIN names as r
       ON l.titles LIKE '%'||r.lookup||'%'")
```

A few notes: I extract the first word from the lookup since you said you want `"hul"` only, and not `"hul india"`. Also in `sql` the `||` means concatenate and `%` means wildcard (which will match anything), so this will match if any of the lookups appear anywhere in the text no matter what is before or after it.

---

Another option using `Reduce` and then merging would be:

```
df$lookup <- Reduce( function(x, y) {x[grepl(y,x)] <- y; x}, c(list(df$titles), names$lookup))
merge(df, names)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer I have made a function including some of the previous comments :

```
df <-  data.frame(title=c("emami paper mills slips 10% on dismal q4 numbers",
                            "jsw steel q4fy17 standalone net profit rises 173.33%",
                            "fmcg major hul q4fy17 standalone net profit rises 6.2"))


names <- c("emami ltd","jsw steel ltd","abc","hul india ltd","tcs")

find_string <- function(data,names){

    ### Clean the names 
    newnames <- gsub("^(\\w+).*","\\1",names)

    ### Loop over the names to find which sentence contain it
    for(i in 1:length(newnames)){

        if(length(grep(newnames[i],df$title)) != 0){
            df$names[grep(newnames[i],df$title)] <- newnames[i]

        }else{
            print(paste(names[i],"not found in the data!"))
        }
    }
    return(df)
}

### Run the function

find_string(df,names)
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: your code does not give what is intended. It seems there is a problem with your for loop.

Comment: You just need to store the result in a new dataframe... new <- find_string(df,names)